# How do you trigger the Looker event in Pokemon x and y?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

I know you have to go to Lumiose City, but I'v been there a lot of times and Looker hasn't called yet.

Comment: What is this looker event?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You must be a Champion (beat the Elite Four and champion then resume playing), get the [Mega Ring upgrade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/136624/why-is-my-mega-stone-not-in-the-location-it-should-be/136625#136625) by doing a Battle Mansion event then battling your rival and meeting Sycamore in Anistar City, and then visit Lumiose City again. Looker called me almost immediately after entering the city, and reentering the city will usually trigger his calls to start the next "chapter" of Looker events.

Comment: I know and I am, do you think that its a bug, because I am champion

Comment: @BigHands5014 Weird. Have you gotten the [Mega Ring upgrade?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/136625/11920) That's another event (post champion) I completed, but I cant' think of much else I did between becoming champ and finding Looker. I did spot my Legendary Bird a couple times and I have moderately high stylishness too (my mega stones cost $150,000 now) in case that affects it

Comment: @BigHands5014 did you go talk with Prof?

Comment: Yes, it worked, all I did was do 1 single battle round in the battle mansion and Serena was there, many thanks =)

Answer (score 1):

all you have to do is do a couple battles in the battle maison, then battle Serena in kiloude city. Then, go to the crystal in Anistar city. There, you will meet the professor. talk to him. then, you'll be able to do the looker missions

Answer (score 0):

once beating the elite four and champion, head to kiloude city and battle your rival, he/she will then tell you to go meet prof. Sycamore in Anistar city, speak to him, once he has upgraded your mega ring, head to lumiose city and looker will call you. Also after the looker story you can get into the Sushi High Roller.

I had the same problem without him calling me, no one tells you that part.

Answer (score 0):

Do some battles at the battle mansion in Kilode City. Find Serena/Calem and they will tell you to go meet Sycamore at the crystal in Anistar City. He will upgrade Mega Ring. Then go to Lumiose and walk a bit. Looker will call you after you go to Rouge Plaza and in one of the areas the Looker bureau and complete missions done!

Answer (score -1):

After you beat the Elite Four, go to Kiloude City, face your rival, just look around the town to find her, after you defeat her she'll tell you to go meet the Professor in Anistar, do so then fly to Lumiose, I don't think it matters which section you go to, the after you walk 1 or 2 steps you get a call on the Holo-Caster, this is Looker. And if you didn't know Looker is a spoof of the Doctor from the long-running British sci-fi show Doctor Who, the 10th Doctor is played by David Tennant and if you go to the Looker Bureau before you trigger the Looker event, the man in there states "The tenant isn't here yet." The TENANT. Tennant Tenant see the similarity? Overall he just looks like the Doctor, and he goes by Looker, nothing else, just Looker, the same way the Doctor goes by the Doctor.

Answer (score -1):

1) Trade ralts for whatever pokemon (like how your friend traded you his or her starter)

2) Battle Serena

3) Go to Lumiose City

4) walk out of the Pokémon Center, and then you will get a Holo Caster from Looker and he will tell you to meet him at Looker Bereau.

Easy as that

Comment: Fairly sure trading for the Ralts is not necessary, I didn't until *well* after completing the Looker missions.

Answer (score -1):

I did it almost the same. I did 1 battle at the Masion, then I beat Calem and upgraded my mega ring. Once I did that, I went to Lumiose and immediately got the call from Looker. Then I did the other missions.

That's all you do.
(Do them in this order.)

Comment: Your answer adds nothing to the accepted one.