# Where's the mega stones in pokemon Y

Tags: pokemon-x-y

I have beaten the Pokemon Y game, I have the Mega Stone upgrade and I've beaten my rival, but the hidden mega stones still aren't appearing between 8-9pm.

How do I get them?

Comment: see [this](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/136624/why-is-my-mega-stone-not-in-the-location-it-should-be)

Comment: Hi james, your question may have already been answered here: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/136624/why-is-my-mega-stone-not-in-the-location-it-should-be, is this the case?